# Combining two regular expressions in java

Tags: html, regex, replace

I have some text like this:

```
[image]bdaypic.jpg[caption]My pic[/caption][/image]
```

I should get output as:

```
<figure><img src='bdaypic.jpg'/><figcaption>My pic</figcaption></figure>
```

I'm using the below code:

```
string = string.replaceAll("\\[image\\](.*?)\\[\\/image\\]", "<figure><img src='$1'/></figure>");
string = string.replaceAll("\\[caption\\](.*?)\\[\\/caption\\]", "<figcaption>$1</figcaption>");
```

but i'm getting output as

```
<figure><img src='bdaypic/><figcaption>My pic</figcaption>'</figure>
```

[caption][/caption] is optional.If it there then only it should be replaced with  tag.

Comment: (almost) obligatory answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/598289

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seems to lie within the first replace. You are capturing everything between the `[image]` tag and replacing it with a quoted version of the content. I merged your two expressions and got what you are after:

```
        String string = "[image]bdaypic.jpg[caption]My pic[/caption][/image]";
        string=string.replaceAll("\\[image\\](.*?)\\[caption\\](.*?)\\[\\/caption\\]\\[\\/image\\]","<figure><img src='$1'/><figcaption>$2</figcaption></figure>");
        System.out.println(string);
```

Yields:

```
<figure><img src='bdaypic.jpg'/><figcaption>My pic</figcaption></figure>
```

Comment: @kotlasaicharanreddy: Can you please define not working?

Comment: I m getting the same input nothing is getting replaced. @npinti

Comment: @kotlasaicharanreddy: It is working on my machine. Are you sure you copied the code exactly from my answer?

Comment: Yes I'm sure ,I checked it again.Still the same result. @npinti

Comment: @kotlasaicharanreddy: Can you please paste the code you are using here?

Comment: `string=string.replaceAll("\\[image\\](.*?)\\[caption\\](.*?)\\[\\/caption\\]\\[\\/image\\]","<figure><img src='$1'/><figcaption>$2</figcaption></figure>");`

Comment: @kotlasaicharanreddy: I've managed to replicate the issue. I think that there might be some non printable character hiding somewhere. I know it might sound daunting, but please try copying the regex by typing it out yourself instead of the usual copy-paste.

Comment: I typed it out by myself and no change in the result.@npinti

Comment: @kotlasaicharanreddy: I've copied what you are using and threw it in Winmerge and it immediately showed that there is something wrong. The issue seems to be within the last `\\[\\/image\\]` block. I deleted it and wrote it again and it worked.

Comment: wrote the whole string again, input not getting replaced.@npinti

Comment: Hey it worked for me now but I have another text like `[image]hello.jpg[/image]`this is not getting replaced. @npinti [caption] tag should be optional.If it present then it should get replaced,if not then i should get output without <figcaption> tags

Comment: @kotlasaicharanreddy: I think it would make sense to check if the string contains the optional text and act accordingly. It would be quicker to implement, because then you would need to have an optional replace, which I do not think can be done within 1 line of code.

Comment: I checked it again i m getting `<figure><img src='bdaypic.jpg'/><figcaption>[caption]My pic[/caption]</figcaption></figure>` @npinti

Comment: INPUT: `[image]bdaypic.jpg[caption]Mypic[/caption][/image]` `[image]bdaypic2.jpg[/image]` CODE 1: `string=string.replaceAll("\\[image\\](.*?)\\[caption\\](.*?)\\[\\/caption\\]\\[\\/image\\]","<figure><img src='$1'/><figcaption>$2</figcaption></figure>");` OUTPUT 1: `<figure><img src='bdaypic.jpg'/><figcaption>My pic</figcaption></figure>` `[image]bdaypic2.jpg[/image]`.

Comment: CODE 2: `string=string.replaceAll("\\[image\\](.*?)(\\[caption\\](.*?)\\[\\/caption\\])?\\[\\/image\\]","<figure><img src='$1'/><figcaption>$2</figcaption></figure>");` OUPTUT 2: `<figure><img src='bdaypic.jpg'/><figcaption>[caption]My pic[/caption]</figcaption></figure>` `<figure><img src='bdaypic2.jpg'/><figcaption></figcaption></figure>` @npinti

Comment: @kotlasaicharanreddy: Please explain your comments.

Comment: If I use code 1 then I'm getting OUTPUT 1 and If I use code 2 then I'm getting OUTPUT 2. CODE 1 is not working for 2nd statement of INPUT and CODE 2 is displaying extra tags[caption][/caption] in OUTPUT 2.

Comment: @kotlasaicharanreddy: This seems to be a different question than the original one. If you have optional segments in your input string, then I'd recommend you have essentially an `if` statement and act accordingly, rather than trying to stuff everything within one expression.

Answer (score 0):

Lot of crazy escaping but you can use:

```
str = str.replaceAll("\\[(image)\\]([^\\[]+)\\[(caption)\\]([^\\[]+)\\[/\\3\\]\\[/\\1\\]", 
             "<figure><img src='$2'/><figcaption>$4</figcaption></figure>");
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/rD6fY3/12)

Comment: I m getting the input as output.It is not getting replaced.@anubhava I don't where I'm doing a mistake.

Comment: I got my mistake  but I have another text like [image]hello.jpg[/image]this is not getting replaced. @anubhava [caption] tag should be optional.If it present then it should get replaced,if not then i should get output without <figcaption> tags

Comment: No you cannot change the nature of question by posting some odd comments. Better you edit the question and show some example input/output.

Answer (score 0):

Ive created a function that will do just that:

```
                   function showreplaced(){
                  var str="[image]bdaypic.jpg[caption]My pic[/caption][/image]";
                 var delimitedStr=str.replace("[image]","").replace("[/caption][/image]","").replace("[caption]","|");
                   var src=delimitedStr.substring(0,delimitedStr.indexOf("|"));
                   var caption=delimitedStr.substring(delimitedStr.indexOf("|")+1);
                    var finalStr="<figure><img src='" + src + "'/><figcaption> " + caption + "</figcaption></figure>";
                 alert(finalStr);
                   }
```